# onblur - how to tell what was clicked; or how to tell if an onclick event is waiting to be run

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick, onblur

In the code below, is there a way to set blurredByClickOnLink to the correct value (without using mouseover or other pointer events to set something before the click happens)?  It should be true if the user blurs the text box by clicking on the link, and false if the user blurs the text box by tabbing or clicking anywhere else.  Thank you for taking a look!

```
<html>
<body>
<input id="myInput" type="text" onblur="var blurredByClickOnLink='???'; console.log('input onblur. blurred by click on link = ' + blurredByClickOnLink);" />
<br/><br/>
<a id="myLink" href="javascript:console.log('a href');void(0);" onclick="console.log('a onclick');">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an event occurs on the DOM, that event is "atomic" in nature.  That means that the event will be processed from the event queue and only then will the next event be processed.  These events are not "grouped" together in any fashion.

When your input element loses focus, that will trigger a `blur` event upon it.  At that point, you can now ask questions about the `blur`.  However there won't be any other state change in the rest of the environment.   What happens next may be a click on the `link` element which can also cause an event to fire.  In this case, a click event on the link.  Since these happen one after the other ... first a blur on the input and then ... later ... a click on the link, you can't know when the blur happens that the next thing to happen will be a click on the link as it hasn't happened yet.

One possible solution would be to set a short timer on the blur of the input.  This timer could fire another function (in say 100msecs) that would then ask the question .. was the link clicked?

This might be sufficient for your puzzle.

The way it helps me to think about such problems is to visualize a queue of requests (an in-box) that  the browser processes one-by-one to change the state of the DOM.  Ask yourself "When I handle a request, do I have what I need to make a decision?"

Comment: Thank you!  So it sounds like what I want (info about the upcoming click event from inside the blur event) cannot be done, because as far the blur event knows, nothing has been clicked on yet.  I am able to use a setTimeout (in either element's click event) to accomplish the behavior that is needed.

I am not familiar with how the Event Queue works, but it sounds like there is no way for the code in the blur event to determine what is in the Event Queue?

Comment: Thats pretty much it.   Imagine filming your browser interactions with a very high speed camera.  The when you move your mouse out of the input field, a blur event fires and could be handled before any subsequent events (such as a click) have occurred.

Comment: I think a better question than what I originally asked would have been: how to tell if an onblur event is waiting while an onmousedown is running.  Unlike blur and click, mousedown and blur happen at the same time but mousedown events get run first.

So, for a specific example of the better question:
In this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/85r4vfqg/14/ - could the variable listOfBlurEventsWaitingToRun get filled in with anything more useful, especially if there are multiple elements that will fire blur events?  And without looking at activeElement?  Can the "event queue" be looked at directly?